# Nested tables, three levels. (ng-repeat on grandchildren?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a three level data structure (parent, child, grandchild) that looks something like this:

```
 $scope.data = [
  { ID: '1', Title: 'Parent Titile 1', children: [
    { ID: '1.1', Title: 'Child Title 1.1', children: [
      {ID: '1.1.1', Title: 'grandchild title 1.1.1'}
      ]
    },
    { ID: '1.2', Title: 'Child Title 1.2', children: [
      {ID: '1.2.1', Title: 'grandchild title 1.2.1'}
      ]
    },
    ]
  }, 
  { ID: '2', Title: 'Parent Titile 2', children: [
    { ID: '2.1', Title: 'Child Title 2.1', children: [
      {ID: '2.1.1', Title: 'grandchild title 2.11'}
      ]
    }
    ]
  }
];
```

Using [smart-table](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/) I managed to display this structure for two levels, I guess it's the same without using smart-tables, but this is how I did it:

```
<table st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="safeCollection" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>#ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
<tr>
    <td> <span ng-class="{'fa fa-plus fa-fw': !row.isCollapsed, 'fa fa-minus fa-fw': row.isCollapsed}"></span> </td>
    <td ng-click="row.isCollapsed = !row.isCollapsed"> {{row.ID}}</td>
    <td> {{row.Title}} </td>
</tr>
<tr uib-collapse="!row.isCollapsed" ng-repeat="child in row.children">
    <td></td>
    <td> {{child.ID}} </td>
    <td> {{child.Title}} </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see, I use two `<tr>` where one of them iterates over the children in each row.

So this will display a table with ng-repeat on parents, and another ng-repeat on its children, using [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) I was able to hide the children with the [collapse](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) directive and show them when parent is clicked, sort of like a tree-view.

What I was unable to do was display the third level (grandchildren). I could not simply create another `<tr>` and go `ng-repeat="grandchild in row.children.children"`.

How can I display the grandchildren in a similar way that I display the children?

Edit: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GStNafWMHqskE5YzB3gI?p=preview) with a working two-level example

obs! I am bad at titles, if you can think of a better suited one, please let me now, so people understand.

Edit2: Thanks to [vanderwijks](http://vanderwijk.info/blog/nesting-ng-repeat-start/) explanation to `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-stop` I managed to do what I wanted, in a way.. I feel this got very complicated, and it gave me an extra `<tr>` just to end the repeat.

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GStNafWMHqskE5YzB3gI?p=preview) with working grandchildren.

In this version the grandchildren are not collapsed when their parent is, which they should, but that's another problem.

Still, I feel as this is not the optimal solution, so I'm still looking for a better way to do this

Comment: You are not approaching this from a good direction. Having multiple tbody's in a table it's against its purpose. Try using nested div's instead of the table. This way, you can go as many levels as you need.

Comment: @MihaiRăducanu I will look into that approach, but I like this solution (so far), I think it looks good, atleast with two levels.

Comment: nvm.. resolved the grandchild collapsing by adding a check for `row.isCollapsed` at the grandchild level tr

Answer (score 1):

This is one simple way to display three levels:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
    <span>{{row.ID}}</span>

    <div ng-repeat="child in row.children">
        <span>{{child.ID}}</span>

        <div ng-repeat="grandchild in child.children">
            <span>{{grandchild.ID}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, and I will probably use this if I can't get the table working, but I'd like to use some functions that tables (smart-table to be precise) offer, so I must keep trying. thanks helpful for answer

Comment: It may prove difficult to represent 3 levels of data in a 2 level table (bi-dimensional)